# Including tikzlibrary in .sty file

Tags: tikz-pgf, package-writing

This might be a silly question, but I know that there is `\RequirePackage{}` for writing a `.sty` file. Is there something like this for requiring the inclusion of a `TikZ` library in a `.sty` file?

I haven't actually tested it yet, but I'm assuming `\usetikzlibrary{}` works just fine inside the `.sty` file?

I was just wondering if something analogous to `\RequirePackage{}` actually exists for this, or if there is a different way to go about requiring the inclusion of a `TikZ` library inside of a `.sty` file.

Comment: There's really no difference between `\RequirePackage` and `\usepackage`, because `\documentclass` does `\let\usepackage\RequirePackage`. It's only customary to use the former in packages and the latter in documents (but before `\documentclass` only `\RequirePackage` can be used). After having loaded `tikz`, you can use `\usetikzlibrary` wherever you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There doesn’t exist something like `\requiretikzlibrary`.

But, `\usetikzlibrary` actually checks whether a library has been already loaded and doesn’t `\input` it again if it is. This is also the reason why one shouldn’t use `\usetikzlibrary` locally in a group. The check whether a library has been loaded is globally defined but the library itself does most likely not use `\gdef`s.

If you don’t want to use the overload of `\usetikzlibrary` you can mimic its behavior by testing the macro `\tikz@library@<library name>@loaded` against `\relax`. If this test is true, it hasn’t been loaded. If it tests positive against `\pgfutil@empty` (or in LaTeX against `\empty` and/or `\@empty` it has been. Note that `\usetikzlibrary` also sets the correct catcodes for `@` (letter, 11) and `|` (other, 12) (and reverts them back to their previos catcode).

```
%%% Lines 4394–4403 of tikz.code.tex
\expandafter\ifx\csname tikz@library@\pgf@temp @loaded\endcsname\relax%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname tikz@library@\pgf@temp @loaded\endcsname=\pgfutil@empty%
  \expandafter\edef\csname tikz@library@#1@atcode\endcsname{\the\catcode`\@}
  \expandafter\edef\csname tikz@library@#1@barcode\endcsname{\the\catcode`\|}
  \catcode`\@=11
  \catcode`\|=12
  \input tikzlibrary\pgf@temp.code.tex
  \catcode`\@=\csname tikz@library@#1@atcode\endcsname
  \catcode`\|=\csname tikz@library@#1@barcode\endcsname
\fi%
```

The rest of the definition of `\use@@tikz@library` is the processing of the possible list that is given to `\usetikzlibrary`. The same applies to `\usepgflibrary` but replace `tikz` with `pgf` in most places.